# need query syntax to fetch latest by PKID after joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables:

```
select * from company
select * from emp_profile
select * from emp_salary_upgrade_tracker


table 1, company_pkid, company_code, company_name

table 2,  emp_profile_pkid,company_fk_id, emp_number, emp_name, salary

table 3, salary_pk_id,emp_profile_fk_id,emp_number, old_salary, current salary
```

whenever an employee's salary is changed, its tracked in emp_salary_upgrade_tracker.

I need to write a query to fetch 
**`company_code, emp_number, emp_name, old_salary, current salary`**

Here the result should have the latest entry ,ie latest salary change from emp_salary_upgrade_tracker.

After joining the tables, i need to fetch the latest from emp_salary_upgrade_tracker(order by pkid may be).

But am clueless of the query syntax. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to get lates ids:

```
select c.company_code, 
       e.emp_number,
       e.emp_name,
       t.old_salary, 
       t.current_salary
from(select emp_profile_fk_id, max(salary_pk_id) as salary_pk_id
     from emp_salary_upgrade_tracker group by emp_profile_fk_id) m
join emp_salary_upgrade_tracker t on m.salary_pk_id = t.salary_pk_id
join emp_profile e on t.emp_profile_fk_id = e.emp_profile_pk_id
join company c on e.company_fk_id = c.company_pkid
```

Comment: but what if there is no value in emp_salary_upgrade_tracker , it doesnt get any value in that scenerio. Sometimes if there is no upgraded salary, still i need to show data from emp_profile table

Comment: Change `join emp_profile` to `right outer join emp_profile`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `row_number` to select the row containing the latest value in the `emp_salary_upgrade_tracker` table when ordered by its primary key.

```
select * from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by esut.emp_number order by esut.salary_pk_id desc) rn 
    from emp_salary_upgrade_tracker esut
    join emp_profile ep on ep.emp_profile_pk_id = esut.emp_profile_fk_id
    join company c on c.company_pk_id = ep.company_fk_id
) t where rn = 1
```